# Reusing existing functions

Tags: language-agnostic

When adding a new feature to an existing system if you come across an existing function that *almost* does what you need is it best practice to:

- Copy the existing function and make your changes on the new copy (knowing that copying code makes your fellow devs cry).

-or-

- Edit the existing function to handle both the existing case and your new case risking that you may introduce new bugs into existing parts of the system (which makes the QA team cry)

  - If you edit the existing function where do you draw the line before you should just create a new independent function (based on a copy)...10% of the function, 50% of the function?

Comment: If the function is complicated enough that it is possible to modify only 10% of the function, then it needs to be refactored anyway.

Comment: The ideal is that your testing is good enough that you can confidently modify the existing function without breaking it. So the fact that there's even a question to ask here pre-supposes that the testing isn't really good enough, and I think the answer is going to depend how bad it is, on a scale from "we have testing, we just don't have time to do everything we'd like", to "appalling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb I tend to follow is that if I can cover the new behaviour by adding an extra parameter (or new valid value) to the existing function, while leaving the code more-or-less "obviously the same" in the existing case, then there's not much danger in changing a function.

For example, old code:

```
def utf8len(s):
    return len(s.encode('utf8')) # or maybe something more memory-efficient
```

New use case - I'm writing some code in a style that uses the null object pattern, so I want `utf8len(None)` to return `None` instead of throwing an exception. I could define a new function `utf8len_nullobjectpattern`, but that's going to get quite annoying quite quickly, so:

```
def utf8len(s):
    if s != None:
        return len(s.encode('utf8')) # old code path is untouched
    else:
        return None # new code path introduced
```

Then even if the unit tests for `utf8len` were incomplete, I can bet that I haven't changed the behavior for any input other than `None`. I also need to check that nobody was ever relying on `utf8len` to throw an exception for a `None` input, which is a question of (1) quality of documentation and/or tests; and (2) whether people actually pay any attention to defined interfaces, or just Use The Source. If the latter, I need to look at calling sites, but if things are done well then I pretty much don't.

Whether the old allowed inputs are still treated "obviously the same" isn't really a question of what percentage of code is modified, it's how it's modified. I've picked a deliberately trivial example, since the whole of the old function body is visibly still there in the new function, but I think it's something that you know when you see it. Another example would making something that was fixed configurable (perhaps by passing a value, or a dependency that's used to get a value) with a default parameter that just provides the old fixed value. Every instance of the old fixed thing is replaced with (a call to) the new parameter, so it's reasonably easy to see on a diff what the change means. You have (or write) at least *some* tests to give confidence that you haven't broken the old inputs via some stupid typo, so you can go ahead even without total confidence in your test coverage.

Of course you want comprehensive testing, but you don't necessarily have it. There are also two competing maintenance imperatives here: 1 - don't duplicate code, since if it has bugs in it, or behavior that might need to change in future, then you're duplicating the bugs / current behavior. 2 - the open/closed principle, which is a bit high-falutin' but basically says, "write stuff that works and then don't touch it". 1 says that you should refactor to share code between these two similar operations, 2 says no, you've shipped the old one, either it's usable for this new thing or it isn't, and if it isn't then leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

You can't always do this, but one solution here would be to split your existing function in other tiny parts, allowing you to use the parts you need without editing all the code, and making it easier to edit small pieces of code.

That being said, if you think you can introduce new bugs into existing parts of the system without noticing it, you should probably think about using units tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should always strive to avoid code duplication. Therefore I would suggest that you try to write a new function that modifies the return value of the already existing function to implement your new feature.

I do realize that in some cases it might not be possible to do that. In those cases you definitely should consider rewriting the existing function without changing its interface. And introducing new bugs by doing that **should** be prevented by unit tests that can be run on the modified function **before** you add it to the project code.

And if you need only part of the existing function, consider extracting a new function from the existing one and use this new "helper" function in the existing and in your new function. Again confirming everything is working as intended via unit tests.